# Number of queries higher (x2) if Doctrine's cache (Redis) is enabled

Tags: php, symfony, caching, redis, doctrine

I'm doing a bulk update on Symfony 3, with Redis installed (snc/redis-bundle) to manage my Doctrine cache.

Without Doctrine's cache or when it's empty (after a flush for example), I've 35 queries sent by Doctrine.
If I enable the cache, this number goes up to 65 (!!).

The difference between those two tests is that when cache is enabled, Doctrine is fetching for each items ONE of the relations (OneToOne).

I am using a custom DQL to prevent Doctrine fetching those relations for every iteration. And it's works pretty fine without cache.

My implementation in the repository:

```php
$batchSize = 30;
$i = 0;
$q = $this
  ->getEntityManager()
  ->createQuery(sprintf(
    'select pa from %s pa LEFT JOIN pa.product p LEFT JOIN pa.productAttribute pat WHERE pa.id IN (:ids)',
    ProductAlert::class
  ))
  ->setParameter('ids', $productAlerts->pluck('id')->all())
;
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();

while (($row = $iterableResult->next()) !== false) {
  /** @var ProductAlert $productAlert */
  $productAlert = $row[0];
  $productAlert->setEmailDate(new DateTime());
  if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    $this->getEntityManager()->clear();
  }
  ++$i;
}
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
$this->getEntityManager()->clear();
```

The  quick workarround is to prevent Doctrine from using cache on this specific query, but I'd rather not ...

Any ideas, fellows ?

Comment: Can you add examples of the additional queries to the question?